# Problem with footnote in captionof

Tags: graphics, captions, footnotes

I have a small problem with footnote. My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{mwart}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
Some text...
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{image1.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Some text\footnote{Source: http://link.com/example-link/}}
\end{center}

Some text
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image2.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Some text\footnote{Source: http://link.com/example-link2/}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have superscript with number at "Some text", but footnote doesn't appear at the bottom of page. Where can be a problem?

Comment: Have you perused the posting [How to place a footnote inside a float environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29916/5001)?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find this post. The solution in this post work in my document.

Comment: Would it be OK to close (not delete!) your posting as a duplicate of the earlier one?

Comment: Ok. No problem.

Comment: @Artek your MWE generates `! Argument of \@caption has an extra }. inserted text> `

Comment: @Artek If the float question answers your problem, why does the example posted here not use a float (so isn't related to the issue in the referenced question)?

Comment: @Mico there's no float in the MWE :(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Part of the earlier posting deals with footnotes inside captions -- immaterial whether the caption's in a float...

Comment: @Mico well the issues are related but the float case is completely different, footnotes don't work in a float anyway the caption isn't relevant: as your answer shows you have to lift the footnotetext out of the float. But it was a comment to the OP to post a MWE that didn't generate errors and demonstrated the problem, not really a comment arguing with you::-)