# Figures enumeration in wrong order

Tags: floats

is there a way to enumerate figures in the order they actually appear in the document, and not in the order they were declared in the source file?

I have the following source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
TEXT1
\begin{figure}[p]
\caption{Figur A}
\end{figure}
TEXT2
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Figur B}
\end{figure}
TEXT3
\end{document}
```

which yields the following two pages:

```
TEXT1
TEXT2

+++++++++++++++
+             +
+   FIGUR B   +
+             +
+++++++++++++++
Fig 2: Figur B

TEXT3

---new page---

+++++++++++++++
+             +
+   FIGUR A   +
+             +
+++++++++++++++
Fig 1: Figur A
```

So, how these two figures appear is exactly what I want, but it is really bad that in the output document, figure 2 comes before figure 1. This is also ugly in the table of figures:

```
Fig 2 "Figur B" page 1
Fig 1 "Figur A" page 2
```

What I want is, that iff tex decides to put figure B after figure A, then it should give figure B the number 1 and figure A the number 2.
I know there are some dirty hacks (setcounter; move figures in source), but obviously I'd like to have an elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I don't think you get the claimed output. Please, show a minimal example starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`. And if you're using `[H]` instead of `[h]`, then it's well explained in the documentation of `float` that `[H]` can make the numbering of floats out of order.

Comment: latex never makes figures float out of order, something is really wrong if the input that you show has the effect that you say it has.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that i am using \usepackage{float} with H option. I edited the question.

Comment: @Sadret Well, the issue with the `[H]` specifier is clearly explained in the manual.

Comment: I suppose your newly-updated code provides one more poignant example of why using the `H` placement specifier can be utterly counterproductive. For sure, if you replace `H` with `ht!`, "Figur B" will be placed *after*, not before, "Figur A".

Comment: @egreg Sure, but that doesn't solve the problem / answers the question.

Comment: @Mico But that is not really what I want. There is a reason I use [H].

Comment: if you insist in use of `[H]` regardless, that you know, that its use leads to your problem, than go ahead  and  add `\clearpage` before   `\begin{figure}[H]`.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, LaTeX *always* outputs floats of a given type -- say, `figure` -- in the sequence in which they are encountered in the document. However, the `H` location specifier falls outside of "normal" circumstances. To achieve its objective, `H` deliberately steps outside of what is normal.

There are only two possible remedies:

- Don't use the `[H]` location specifier. Consider using `[ht!]` instead.
- Or, as @Zarko has already commented, if you insist on using `[H]` anyway, be prepared to insert `\clearpage` *before* typing `\begin{figure}[H]`.