# Prevent footnotes from sticking together, moving to next page

Tags: positioning, footnotes

I hit a situation where it appears like latex has a passion for putting footnotes together, which causes it even to move a footnote away from the page on which it is referenced.

[EDIT: As Ulrike Fischer pointed out in the comments, latex has no such mechanism built-in. The behavior thus must be a symptom of some other issue.]

To be precise, I have two pages as follows:

- Page 1

  - Figure 1
  - Footnote 1 is defined
- Page 2

  - Figure 2
  - Footnote 2 is defined
  - Footnote 3 is defined

Now instead of putting Footnote 1 on Page 1, latex puts Footnote 1 on Page 2, together with Footnote 2 and 3. There would be enough space on Page 1 to fit Footnote 1. If I make the page bigger using `\enlargethispage`, nothing happens for a while until it moves *all three* footnotes on Page 1.

I'm not providing a MWE because I think the issue is quite specialized and hard to reproduce.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? What did you do against that? Is there a penalty or so I can set for moving footnotes to another page?

Comment: Your claim is wrong: nothing in latex tries to keep footnotes together. Your code is doing something curious and you should show an example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, ok, thanks for the information. I edited my question to include this.

Comment: really you should provide an example it is almost impossible to guess what is happening, for example are page 1 or page 2 float pages? (latex can not place footnptes on float pages by default)

Comment: Footnotes inside floats are tricky at best, since you really don't know what page the float will wind up on.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29916/how-to-place-a-footnote-inside-a-float-environment

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The problem was that the figure on Page 2 contained `\tablefootnote` commands. I'm not sure how the `tablefootnote` package works, but there *does* seem to be some interaction with previously placed footnotes.

I worked around this issue by replacing the `\tablefootnote` command by a `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` pair and moving the `\footnotetext` far enough down.